# Real time send of emails data architecture in salesforce marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio, triggered-send, transactional-messaging-api

This is our current set-up to send emails..

1. Customer places an order
2. Daily data populated into FTP
3. SFMC Automation will pickup this data
4. SFMC Journey triggered
5. Email is sent

But what I want is to send real time send out of emails instead of file drops (FTP).
So I wanted to know, how to make changes in the architecture?

Also how to make changes in the journey or to the automation to target only Newsletter subscribers?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to utilise the [Transactional Messaging API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/transactional-messaging-get-started.htm), and call it from the system where your customer places an order. This will give you superior performance (latency between API call and actual send will be minimal).

As you probably will have an arbitrary number of order lines, I will suggest you take a look at [BuildRowsetFromXML](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/buildrowsetfromxml.htm) function, and pass these orderlines as XML in the REST payload.

I assumed you would send order confirmation emails, hence I didn't expect to validate against whether or not this person is an actual subscriber. If you need an easy way of avoiding sending to unsubscribed customers, you should maintain the status in All Subscribers, and use Commercial send classification, which will automatically prevent the email from going out to anyone with status of Unsubscribed in All Subscribers list.

Alternatively, if you don't maintain the status in All Subscribers, you could use the traditional journey with API entry event (as suggested by [Gortonington](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/12730/gortonington)) and use contact filter to check the status in a data extension within your contact model.

We have little ability to help you with more detailed design, with the little information provided by you.

Comment: Can also adjust/recreate the journey entry event to be API (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_admit_contacts_via_api.htm&type=5) and insert via that or utilize a Triggered Send Definition instead of Transactional Messaging if that fits better for your needs.

Comment: thanks a lot both of you. I would like to go with second option that is Journey  with API entry event  and then use contact filter. I am new to SFMC, by status do you mean a separate attribute called status in DE that shows if the customer is subscribed or not?

Comment: Correct, @Deeksha. Not being aware of your data model, makes it impossible for me to suggest where you should look for this field.

Comment: sorry, I have a question @LukasLunow.  I am using API entry event in Journey Builder, Now I have a DE with all contacts(both subscribed & unsubscribed) coming into journey .But here I want to send only to subscribers.
If I have applied commercial send classification (as you mentioned in your answer)  will the email go only to subscribers through the journey ??